# How do you fix the occasional blank page when submitting a form?

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, form-submit

The most troublesome bug is the **occasional** one; there is no definite way to reproduce it.

I've searched a lot on this topic,
and the most probable reason is the charset,
and I've taken some actions by setting the default `charset` as `utf8` in `.htaccess` (I'm using Apache),
but it still happens, again **occasionally!**

Have you guys any tips other than setting the default charset to fix it?

As a side note that according to my own experience it happens mostly when the form is submitted from IE, if not all.

Comment: And you are using what language? Perhaps you can post some of the form handling code?

Comment: I'm using PHP now but I think the problem is generic,it also happens when I was using jsp or .net

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PHP?

Usually any time I hit a blank page, it's because there's an elusive bug in php someplace and errors are turned off.

Just an alternative path you might investigate.

Comment: The problem,as I said,is I can't reproduce it with the same posting data,what kind of bug can it be?Also it seems to me that firefox never met such kind of issue,yet...So I doubt whether it's a pure php bug